# Python error : function got multiple values for keyword argument for value

Tags: python, arguments, keyword

```
search(lane,value=None,start=105,stop=115,GUI=True) # -> function definition
search(lane,value=value,start=start, stop=stop,GUI=True) # -> function call
```

I get the error

```
"search()" got multiple keyword argument for value"
```

I understand when this error comes up - if I had a function definition like below

```
def func(a):
    ...
```

and if I called it as `func(0,a)` where I am passing 2 parameters instead of 1, I would end up with the error message.

I dont follow why I get it when the number of arguments I am calling with the function call matches the parameters in the definition.

Please advise.

Comment: Don't call it with keywords, just call it with the values. `search(lane, None, 105, 115, True)`

Answer (score 0):

So you are doing something like this ?. This works for me.

```
def search(lane,value=None,start=105,stop=115,GUI=True):
    print "Do something"

value = 1
start = 1
stop = 1
lane = 1

search(lane,value=value,start=start, stop=stop,GUI=True)
```

Is there maybe another function named `search` somewhere in your code??
Or maybe there is an import that calls a search function that you don't know about try renaming your function to something different Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: jramirez - "search" is a function defined in "Class E" and "search" is called in "class R" as follows  obj = E(self) ---instantiation and obj.search(lane,value=value,start=start, stop=stop,GUI=True) ----func call

Comment: You don't add `self` in a class initiator. Update your question with the actual code you are running.

Comment: Burhan Khalid - that's not true - what I pass to classname in -> "obj = classname()" depends on the __init__() of "classname"

Comment: So search is a method of class E? Then the definition requires 'self' as the first argument, as it's passed automatically...

Comment: Ben - But the function call is from some other class, not class E..Do you still think I should use self?

Answer (score 0):

## If you are seeing something similar to this error message

it could be because you are missing a `self` parameter in your class call. I ended up at this post with the same error message and took a bit to figure out that was the problem. Posting this here for other lost souls.